# How to write two logger files separately in python

Tags: python, logging

I have a logger function in 3 python scripts. Three python scripts has logger function. When i trigger 3rd python scripts, a logger file was created but i didn't see any logs there. But i can see that log was logged in another log file.

My code :

```
#First env.py
#here we take variable from here
#logger 
FORMAT='%(hostname)s : %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(filename="/balaji/empty/log/em.log",format=Format)
_logconfig={'hostname': _host)
logger=logging.getLogger(_name_)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
server="DEV"
host="Admin"

#Trigger.py
#this code read variables from env.py
#logger 
FORMAT='%(hostname)s : %(message)s '
logging.basicConfig(filename="/balaji/empty/log/em.log",format=Format)
_logconfig={'hostname': _host)
logger=logging.getLogger(_name_)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)`

#Forgot.py
#this code read variables from env.py
#logger
FORMAT='%(hostname)s : %(message)s '
logging.basicConfig(filename="/balaji/empty/log/forgot.log",format=Format)
_logconfig={'hostname': _host)
logger=logging.getLogger(_name_)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Here  i didnt see any log files in forgot.log.instead of that,i can see forgotpy logs were logged in em.log

Comment: Do you run all 3 scripts together in single python instance ? If yes, logging.basicConfig will work only once.

Comment: No it will be different.